# Integrate Django with Spring Boot

Tags: django, spring, mongodb, microservices, grpc

I'm using gRPC microservices. The backend is built on Spring Boot connected with the Mongo database. The front end is implemented on the Django framework.

Can you help with how to connect Django with Spring and pass the CURD operations?

Thanks
Bhavesh Asanabada

Comment: Please go through the link `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask` to understand how u should ask a question in this stackoverflow platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you try to consume your GRPC/REST services in python framework?. Is you able to test your springboot grpc service using postman. https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/